# Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, script-tag

Here I have included scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-3.3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-3.3.2/select2.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<input  type="hidden" id="parcele" />
```

and jquery code on the bottom of page:

```
<script>
function formatValues(data) {
    return data.ime_prezime;
}

$('#parcele').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "json.php",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    width: "300px",
    formatResult: formatValues,
    formatSelection: formatValues,
    multiple: true
});
</script>
```

but I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'`

What is wrong here? I dont get it...

Comment: mu json.php file is fine... also this same code work on other page that have just this code ...

Comment: instead of using the js/css files from github use one from a cdn like http://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2/

Comment: GitHub will often block requests from it (when treated like a CDN).

Comment: I try it, but again is the same, also when I host files again is the same ... my jquery code is on bottom of page, and HTML is in an modal window ...

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/3rmXL47ZgnKjf5Nj5OQ5?p=preview

Comment: I know, but for me dont work ... look at: http://agroagro.com/template/tema/zadaci.html#

Comment: look on the source code on the bottom and on source code on the top ...

Comment: so what can be a problem in my code? what stop script to load ?

Comment: is there any solution for my problem? I also try to change select2 to Select2 but dont work

Comment: Is your code in document.ready handler?

Comment: yes I add, document rady, but again dont work ... http://i.imgur.com/8s9D2KR.jpg....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until jQuery and `select2.js` have loaded:

```
function formatValues(data) {
    return data.ime_prezime;
}

$(document).ready(function() { // add this
    $('#parcele').select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: "json",
            url: "json.php",
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        },
        width: "300px",
        formatResult: formatValues,
        formatSelection: formatValues,
        multiple: true
    });
}); // add this
```

**EDIT:** I found your problems:

1. You don't have any elements with `id` "parcele" on your actual page at http://agroagro.com/template/tema/zadaci.html# - I think you are thinking of the elements with `id` "parcela" (notice the "a" instead of an "e").
2. You actually have two elements with the `id` "parcela", but HTML ids have to be unique.

To fix this: Rename one of the elements with the `id` "parcela", then use one of them where you have "parcele" in your existing JavaScript.

Also, just to verify that everything works if you fix the naming problems, I created [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/rTkrz/), which works correctly.

Comment: nice , but again dont work for me: http://agroagro.com/template/tema/zadaci.html look at browser console...

Comment: Try temporarily disabling all of the JavaScript files other than jQuery and select2.js -- I bet one of them is conflicting. See this discussion: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/66